# Selectively extracting symbology from layer file in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, symbology, arcgis-9.2

I'd like to classify polygons within a shapefile according to one of my attribute fields, lets call it LITHOLOGY. I have another field in the same shapefile that is associated with a standardised colour code layer file (.lyr), the field is filled with colour codes, lets call this field COLOUR.

I can apply the correct colour symbology to my shapefile by importing the .lay file symbology linked to the COLOUR field. Great. Now, the labels for the symbology are just colour codes. I'd like to apply this colour symbology (which is linked to my COLOUR field to my LITHOLOGY field (which have the right names).

How can I do this?

When importing the symbology from the layer layer file, my options to import "just the symbols or "just the classification" are greyed out.

When trying to produce a map, I either have:

1. a correctly coloured map with an undesirable series of numbers in my legend, or
2. I have a legend showing my LITHOLOGY field but my map colours are totally arbitrary.

Unfortunately .lay files can't be opened up and modified and they can't be easily converted to any sensible format either. There's close on 1000 different colour categories, so manual editing of each LITHOLOGY unit is out of the question.

Has anybody run into this issue, because I can't find any solutions on-line?